# Using Flush bar to auto show notification when screen load

Tags: flutter

I'm using flush bar for customize when notice my user. It's very easy to use but user must ontap a button or somethings like this, the notification show. Like this

```
           onPressed: (){
                Flushbar(
                  title:  "Hey Ninja",
                  message:  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
                  duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),              
                )..show(context);
              },
```

How can I make this auto show when screen load.
I tried this code below but it's work not smooth

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Flushbar(...)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming The class is extending Stateful Widget , You could call it by overriding initState() method